How to display binary data in a column chart?
I have a appsheet table, with multiple binary fields. I would like to create a column chart where each column represents one of these fields and the height of the column is determined by the number of rows in that table that equal "true".
I feel like this should be very simple, but I have spent hours trying to get it. How can I achieve this?
